# Randomforest parameter tuning R(caret) and Python(scikit learn)?

Tags: python, r, random-forest

**Question:** is it possible, or even necessary, to perform a cross-validation check to tune the parameters of a Python randomforest implementation (eg scikit learn) when training a new model, as can be done in R's caret?

**Background R**: When using R's caret's randomforest library, one can tune the parameters by performing a n-fold cross validation, e.g.

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                          number = 10,
                          repeats = 5,
                          verboseIter = TRUE,
                          allowParallel = TRUE,
                          summaryFunction = multiClassSummary)
rf1 <- train(Class ~ .,
         data = train_transformed,
         method = "rf",
         metric = "Accuracy",
         tuneGrid = my_grid1,
         trControl = train_control)
```

This outputs -

```
## Aggregating results
## Selecting tuning parameters
## Fitting mtry = 1 on full training set
```

or whatever mtry is the best for a dataset.

**Background Python:**  Using scikit learn, one can instantiate a randomforest regressor and can perform a cross-validation check on that regressor

```
RFRegModel = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)
cv = cross_validate(RFRegModel,X,y,cv=5,verbose=1)
print(cv['test_score'])
```

the difference here is that the cross validation doesn't appear to influence the tuning of the randomforest parameters, as I think it does in R. I think all that is happening here is that we are taking random subsamples of the training data set and testing the implementation of the

**Question again**: is it possible to train the model in python in a similar manner as is done in caret, i.e. by forcing an n-folds cross-validation
parameter tuning?  or, is this even necessary? Is the caret implementation overconstrained by it's methodolgy?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV()` or a similar function regarding the type of "search" (grid, random, ...) you would like to conduct. This function does hyperparameter tuning and uses cross validation when doing so and the `cv` parameter will allow you to specify the number of folds.